# .hasNext() and .next() cause infinite while loop

Tags: java, input, while-loop, logic, palindrome

I'm in a beginner level coding class and this is my assignment: 
   Write a void method called palindromeCheck that takes NO argument. The method should have functionality to check whether or not the word(s) is(are) a palindrome and print to the screen all of the palindromes, one per line. Also, the last line of the output should have the message: “There are x palindromes out of y words provided by user” (where x is the number of palindrome words detected, and y is the total number of words entered by user). Hint: for this lab exercise you will need the following methods on String objects: length() gives the length of a string (that is, the number of characters it contains) and charAt(i) - gives the character at position i.
   Since the input entered is supposed to be separated by white space I'm confused on how to create the while loop that iterates per word entered. My professor gave us help in the form of a skeleton for the method she wants us to create. In that skeleton is a while loop that performs actions for each word entered

```
while (keyboard.hasNext()){
someWord = keyboard.next();
// some code that performs actions
}
```

This while loop works but after it's done and supposed to terminate it just prompts to enter more input. Here is my current code below, which should be finished aside from this logical error.

```
public static void palindromeCheck(){
    String someWord = ""; // Stores words read from user input
    int count = 0;        // keeps track of Palindrome words only
    int total = 0; // Counts the total number of lines read from the given text file
    int score = 0; // used as a condition to count palindrome words   
    System.out.println("Enter some words separated by white space."); 
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (keyboard.hasNext()) { // for each word user enters
        someWord = keyboard.next(); // store each word in a string variable and then do operations
        score = 0;
        int n = (someWord.length()-1);
        for (int i = 0; i < (someWord.length()-2); i++){
            for (int j = (someWord.length()-1); i < (someWord.length()-2); j--){
                j = n;
                n--;
                if(someWord.charAt(i) == someWord.charAt(j)){
                    break;
                }
                else
                    score++;
            }
        }
        if(score == 0){ // if word is palindrome adds to counter
            count++;
        }
        total++; // increment number of words as you read each one
        //System.out.println("  " + total + " " + someWord);   // test
    }
    System.out.println("There are " + count + " palindromes out of " + total + " words provided by user.");
}
```

Comment: Can you post your main method?

Comment: When is it supposed to terminate?

Comment: @m0skit0 `import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab5
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        palindromeCheck();
    }`

Comment: @shmosel the loop is supposed to terminate after all the words entered by the user are read.

Comment: @sinclair I don't know what you mean, everything is within the loop that has to do with manipulating the strings and I only call palindromeCheck() once in main

Comment: @m0skit0 sorry if my main didn't post correctly but all it is is palindromeCheck() being called once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't depend on `keyboard.hasNext()` to tell you when your program should stop.  A keyboard is basically an infinite source of input, so `keyboard.hasNext()` might **never** return `false`.  If there is some data from the previous input line that hasn't been processed yet, it will return `true` immediately.  But if all the data from the previous line was used up, `keyboard.hasNext()` will just sit and wait for you to type another line, and then return `true` once you've hit ENTER.

Since you can't depend on `keyboard.hasNext()` to tell you that it's time to stop processing words, you have to program some other way to decide when the program should stop.

The nicest way, from your user's point of view, is to read one entire line of input, process all the words on that line, and then stop.  You use `keyboard.nextLine()` to read a whole line of input:

```
String inputLine = keyboard.nextLine();
```

After that, you have any number of choices as to how to break that line up into individual words.  Here are examples of two ways.

**Use a `Scanner(String)`:**

```
String inputLine = keyboard.nextLine();
Scanner wordScn = new Scanner(inputLine);
while (wordScn.hasNext())
{
    String someWord = wordScn.next();
    // ... process someWord
}
```

**Use `String.split(String delimRegEx)`:**

```
String inputLine = keyboard.nextLine();
String[] words = inputLine.split("\\s+");
for (String someWord : words)
{
    // ... process someWord
}
```

The `"\\s+"` argument to `split` is a **regular expression** that specifies the delimiter between words, meaning "white-space (`\s`), one or more of (`+`)".

Answer (score 0):

Type Ctrl/z (Ctrl/d on Windows - or is it the other way round?). It'll stop all right.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop appears to be wrong, with what you have, you are taking new input on each loop and this continues ad infinitum. (ie, user enters something, presses enter, loop starts again; rinse and repeat). I'm guessing this isn't what you were aiming for so...

You could take input, store it in a String and then split that String into multiple other Strings, storing them in an array. You can then iterate though each String in that array and compare the characters.

By the way, the code as posted crashes with certain words.

Please see updated my version here... :-)

```
    public static void palindromeCheck(){

        String someWord = ""; // Stores words read from user input
        int count = 0;        // keeps track of Palindrome words only
        int total = 0; // Counts each word/String read from the array
        System.out.println("Enter some words separated by white space."); 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Get input from user
        String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();

        int nextWord = 0;
        String[] userInputArray = userInput.split("\\s+"); //Split into separate words (returns an array)

        while (nextWord<userInputArray.length) { //for each word in array        

            someWord = userInputArray[nextWord++]; // store each word in a string variable and then do operations, increments nextWord 

            int lastChar = (someWord.length()-1);
            int firstChar = 0;
            int loops = (someWord.length())/2;
            for(int i = 0;i<loops;i++){
                //If characters don't match, break out of loop, otherwise carry on
                if(someWord.charAt(firstChar++)!=someWord.charAt(lastChar--)) //move to next/previous characters once checked
                   break;
                //if we've checked the whole word, then we've found a palindrome
                if(i>=loops-1){
                    count++; 
                }
            }
            total++; // increment number of words as you read each one
        }
        System.out.println("There are " + count + " palindromes out of " + total + " words provided by user.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't learned about `string.split` yet so I want to avoid using that. After looking at these answers for a little bit I came up with a work around, for anyone looking at this in the future that may find it useful. And I fixed the problem about my program crashing with certain words like `boop`. I fixed my program by adding in two things...

This

```
System.out.println("Enter some words separated by white space. Type exit at anytime to receive results.");
```

and

```
someWord = keyboard.next().toLowerCase(); // store each word in a string variable and then do operations
        if(someWord.equals("exit")){
            break;
        }
```

and fixed the crash on certain words by adding a `break` statement to the else in this if/else statement

```
if(someWord.charAt(i) == someWord.charAt(j)){
    break;
 }
 else{
    score++;
    break;
 }
```

Here is my updated and final code below.

```
 public class Lab5
{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        palindromeCheck();
    }

public static void palindromeCheck(){
        String someWord = ""; // Stores words read from user input
        int count = 0;        // keeps track of Palindrome words only
        int total = 0; // Counts the total number of lines read from the given text file
        int score = 0; // used as a condition to count palindrome words
        String exit = "exit";

        System.out.println("Enter some words separated by white space. Type exit at anytime to receive results."); 
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (keyboard.hasNext()) { // for each word user enters
            someWord = keyboard.next().toLowerCase(); // store each word in a string variable and then do operations
            if(someWord.equals("exit")){
                break;
            }
            score = 0;
            int n = (someWord.length()-1);
            for (int i = 0; i < (someWord.length()-2); i++){
                for (int j = (someWord.length()-1); i < (someWord.length()-2); j--){
                    j = n;
                    n--;
                    if(someWord.charAt(i) == someWord.charAt(j)){
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        score++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(score == 0){ // if word is palindrome adds to counter
                count++;
            }
            total++; // increment number of words as you read each one
        }
        System.out.println("There are " + count + " palindromes out of " + total + " words provided by user.");
    }
}
```